# React - Material-UI - Typescript: makeStyles hook gives Invalid Hook Call inside a function component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, makestyles

I really don't understand what am I doing wrong.

I am using the `makeStyles` hook as described inside the (javascript) documentation, and I am getting this `Invalid Hook Call`. I am using TypeScript 4.1.2, React 17.0.1 and React Types 17.0.0.

Here is the component code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Theme, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

interface Props
{
    isVisible: boolean;
}

const useStyles = makeStyles( ( theme: Theme ) => ( {
    root: {
        background: 'red',
        height: 100,
    },
} ) );

const Nav: React.FC<Props> = ( props: Props ) =>
{
    const { isVisible } = props;

    const classes = useStyles( {} );

    return (
       <div className={classes.root}>

       </div>
    );
};

export default Nav;
```

[image: Error message:]

Comment: Weird. I tried to run your `useStyle` hook in my React project and it's working. I don't use ts. Can you show some more information about error ?

Comment: I will add it right away.

Comment: It looks like the TS just messes up your `material-ui makeStyles` hook. Witch is weird. Because I am just calling a hook like I would normally do if I was using .jsx files in stead of .tsx

Comment: @AndreyRF, what do you think? Have you encountered this before?

Answer (score 1):

The answer was simpler than I would have thought. It seems that with `"react-scripts":"4.0.3"`, the code works. I don't remember what version of `cra` I was using previously(I updated it before I checked), but with the latest version looks like it is working.

Here is what I did:

1. I created a new branch in my git.
2. I completely deleted the app
3. I typed in the terminal `npm i -g create-react-app`
4. I created a new react app: `create-react-app <your file> --template typescript`
5. Finally I added the dependencies and libraries: `npm i @material-ui/core @material-ui/icons @material-ui/lab <other-libraries-here> ... @types/material-ui <other-types-here> ...`
6. I changed, as I did before, the `tsconfig.json` file as the [material-ui documentation](https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/#typescript) suggests (I left the `strictNullChecks` to false as a personal preference)
7. I ran the start script using `npm/yarn start`.

I hope this answer helps somebody that encountered this problem! Happy hacking!